# mvn install -P docker-buld-image is not producing an updated jar file after changes

Tags: java, docker, maven, kubernetes

I have a Spring project to which I have made two very basic changes:

1. `logger.info("testing changes made");`
2. `return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT); //previously HttpStatus.OK`

I then:

1. git committed the changes (not really necessary)
2. `mvn clean install -P docker-build-image`
3. `docker tag my-service:old-tag  my-service:new-tag`

I then used this image to install the service in a kubernetes pod as follows:

```
echo " deploying auth service"
helm uninstall auth
kubectl delete pod -l app.kubernetes.io/name=auth
kind load docker-image my-service:new-tag
helm install auth ./auth --wait
```

The trouble is: I am never getting any changes. I only see the output from the old version of the application.

What is going on here? This is very strange to me. This feels very much like a maven|docker plugin kind of problem. Or, is it a kubernetes|kind|helm problem?

Comment: 1. run your new image in docker locally and make sure it does what you expect. 2. look at your running pod and see that the image has the tag you expect.

Answer (score 0):

mvn install will just install the package.

You should do mvn package before install to make new jar file.

Comment: No, `mvn install` comes later in the Maven Build Lifecycle. Hence, every `mvn install` will **always** also run the *package* build phase. See the [official maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#a-build-lifecycle-is-made-up-of-phases)

Comment: I already left the comment why this is not a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was experiencing resulted from the docker-building module was using an old snapshot to build the docker image. The wrong dependency was being used in the POM file of that module. I changed the dependency and everything worked just fine.